# Edit XPS file in C# Forms application in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xps

I want to Open a .xps file in my C# Forms (Visual Studio 2008) application and then I want to add some contents on top of the document and then save document with different name.

Is this possible to achieve without creating WPF application?

Comment: Do you need to display the file or just add content through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply trying to edit the xps document without displaying it, then yes, you can skip the WPF user interface. Check out the [System.Windows.Xps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.aspx) and [System.Windows.Xps.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.aspx) namespaces for manipulating the document.

Comment: I wanted to display the file as well :(